# Is there a bug in Android concerning Set<String> in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is it possible that there's a bug in the Android platform?
I've been trying to overwrite a Set in my SharedPreferences

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();

Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
set.add("one");
set.add("two");
set.add("three");
editor.putStringSet("set", set);
editor.commit();
showSet(prefs.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));
```

This shows the correct Strings: "one", "two" and "three".

But then I want to remove "three".

```
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>());
set.remove("three");
editor.putStringSet("set", set);
editor.commit();
showSet(prefs.getStringSet("set", new HashSet<String>()));
```

This also gives me the correct Strings: "one" and "two".

But if I **stop the application and restart it**. My SharedPreferences will still return me "one", "two" and "three".

I've tried the same with booleans and Strings, but that seems to be working just fine.
I've explained everything on [my blog here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/08/android-bug-stringset-in.html).

*Note: I've put a log in onDestroy() so when I stop the app, I can see onDestroy() is called so the lifecycle methods have been executed.*

Comment: Can you show that where are you executing the above statements and where are you trying to print it again on restart?

Comment: In onCreate() I define the prefs and editor. The other 2 blocks of code are executed with a button and an onClickListener.

Comment: I print it again in onCreate()

Comment: There is a less chance of it being a bug. It might be of more help if you include the relevant section of the Activity in question ( if its not proprietary ). i.e your onCreate functrion and the click listers etc

Comment: I had similar problem once even for string. The preferences were not holding the access_token on app restart. I removed the editor object and used prefs.edit() everytime I need to save something. It worked for me.